# Pass alternate attribute as GET

Tags: forms, http, input, get

I have the following input:

```
<input id="whereInput" type="text" name="where" placeholder="around..." geodata="-73.6050237,45.5511518" value="Current Location">
```

I want to pass the geodata as the value to the get parameter, but not its value.

in other words I want `where=-73.6050237,45.5511518` but not `where=Current%20Location`

Thanks,

Comment: How are you sending your request? Kindly post your code.

Comment: You'll need to dabble with javascript a bit for that, most likely on the onsubmit of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value you actually want to submit in a hidden input with a different name.

If the submitted value is "Current Location" then read the data from the other field instead.